# Newb Voltage regulator pin-out question

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, pinout

So I just put my first complicated circuit together and of coarse it doesn't work, good news is I found the problem.

Given a [LA5752](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/413/LA5752-pdf.php) voltage regulator I assumed the hookup was pin1->Vin, pin3->GND and pin5->5 Volts. For some reason I'm only getting .8-1.1V on pin 5... Do I need any other pins hooked up? Could someone help me out?

[image: Regulator pin-out]

Comment: A schematic is required.

Comment: What part would you like? I just want to supply 12V in and get 5V out

Comment: The power supply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know it's a switching regulator, right? So it won't work without a suitable external inductor and diode? See the application circuit in the datasheet.

Pin 5 is the Soft Start input. Connect it to ground via a capacitor (the app circuit suggests 1 uf)

Comment: Nooo!!! I hoped that was a suggestion, but it makes sense too. Thanks for the help, it's obvious I need to do more research before spending my paycheck over at mouser haha

Comment: Soft Start/Cap is not needed, then it can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet is pretty short, but it gives you exactly what you need to get it working. Bare minimum, you need an input and output cap, a diode, and an inductor. The C3, Soft Start Capacitor can be omitted if you don't need the Soft Start Function. Leave the pin floating.
[image]